# why I couldn't call js function in another part of a html page?

Tags: javascript

Why does the first JavaScript snippet work, and not the second?:

```js
<script>
  commenta();
  function commenta(){
    alert('test');
  }
</script>
```

```js
<script>
  commenta();
</script>

<script>
  function commenta(){
    alert('test');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It is called [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, it works because of [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Hoisting). Javascript engine will move all the declarations to the top of function/global definition.

But second example is throwing an error because **Hoisting won't work across `<script>` tags.**

Try swapping the order of script tag, it should work.

[fiddle: Your code (Before swap)](http://jsfiddle.net/wxm4bg1m/)

[fiddle: After swap](http://jsfiddle.net/wxm4bg1m/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`commenta();
   function commenta()
   {
       alert('test');
   }`

In this example, the browser will move all function declarations to the top of the script block and then execute the call.

In the other example, the browser does not yet know how to execute commenta since it hasn't parsed that part of the DOM yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function before the function is registered, as the 2 tags are registered separately under different tags, where the when the statements are included together under one script tag they are registers as a whole.  It's best practice to only call a function after it's been declared.